# How to change Terminal background color when I open new tab?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

I wanted to change color when I login to remote server by ssh.

The problem solved by this question.

[How do I make the apple terminal window auto change colour scheme when I ssh to a specific server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157959/how-do-i-make-the-apple-terminal-window-auto-change-colour-scheme-when-i-ssh-to)

But the solution above have a little problem.

1. Connet to remote server by ssh. (Background color is changed)
2. Open new terminal Tab.
3. This Tab's background is still changed.

So I want to "reset" background color when I open new Terminal Tab.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

By default, Terminal creates new tabs with the same settings as the current tab. You can change it to always use your default profile for new tabs in **Preferences > Startup** by changing **New tabs open with:** to **Default Settings**.

Note that there’s a built-in way to automatically set the background color for specific commands instead of using the script from that other answer:

You can set the name of a settings profile to a command name and Terminal will select that profile when you create a new terminal via either **Shell > New Command…** or **Shell > New Remote Connection…**.

For example, duplicate your default profile, name it “ssh” and set its background color to red. Then use **New Command…** to run `ssh host.example.com`.

It also matches on arguments, so you can have it choose different settings for different remote hosts, for example. You could have one named “ssh host.example.com” with a blue background and another named “ssh” with a red background to handle any ssh commands that don’t match other profiles.